# Onclick - nudge div down

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the following javascript on a div to goto a link:

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="location.href='http://www.test.com';">
```

Is it possible, onclick, to nudge the div down by 3px so it looks like it's being clicked via javascript? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Maybe a silly question - but why not just use a button instead of creating a div and them emulating the button (cursor / depress) ?!?! and just style it ... some basic style here -> http://jsfiddle.net/tCWVJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [CSS Pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp):

```
div:active{
 padding-top:3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prZ7w/1/

Comment: What's the browser compatibility with pseudo-classes on divs?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do: http://jsfiddle.net/XnqSE/

The key is to set `position: relative` so that the `top:3px` can have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to simulate this (arguably) is to define 2 style attributes for the button, and change the id when the button is clicked.

Here's a similar question:

[HTML page refreshment with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386698/html-page-refreshment-with-javascript/8387402#8387402)